# AutocompleteTextView item click not firing as excepted

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have an AutoCompleteTextView which behaves like a Spinner, so no possibility of input and dropdown menu when I click on it. When the dropdown menu appear and I click an item for the first time the code fires on `SpinnerCapacità_ItemSelected` but it exits without firing the statements I need. At the second click everything works perfectly.
This is my XML layout:

```
  <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:weightSum="100"   
 android:orientation="horizontal">
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="55"      style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu">
  <AutoCompleteTextView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:inputType="none"
   android:layout_weight="60"
   android:hint="@string/colorazione"
   android:id="@+id/SpinnerCapacità" />
  </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
  <com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/predefinito"
   android:layout_weight="40"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:checked="true"
   android:id="@+id/chbCol"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is `SpinnerCapacità_ItemSelected` event:

```
        private void SpinnerCapacità_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e) 
    {
        AutoCompleteTextView SpinnerCapacità = (AutoCompleteTextView)sender;
        SwitchMaterial chb = View.FindViewById<SwitchMaterial>(Resource.Id.chbCap);
        var value = Preferences.Get("DefCapacità", "24");
        SpinnerCapacità.ItemClick += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (value == SelectedTextOfTheDropdownMenu) chb.Checked = true;

            else chb.Checked = false;
        };
    }
```

And finally this code is inside my `OnCreateView`

```
            AutoCompleteTextView SpinnerCapacità = v.FindViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(Resource.Id.SpinnerCapacità);
        SpinnerCapacità.ItemClick += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs>(SpinnerCapacità_ItemSelected);
        var ArrayCapacità = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource(
                Application.Context, Resource.Array.array_capacità, Resource.Drawable.spinner_item);
        ArrayCapacità.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleDropDownItem1Line);
        SpinnerCapacità.Adapter = ArrayCapacità;
```

Also I don't know in this line `if (value == SelectedTextOfTheDropdownMenu)` how to get the text of dropdown's selected item. Thanks

Comment: No ways of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in this way:
Declaration of click event

```
SpinnerColorazione.ItemClick += SpinnerColorazione_ItemSelected;
```

Method

```
private void SpinnerCapacità_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e) 
{
    AutoCompleteTextView SpinnerCapacità = (AutoCompleteTextView)sender;
    SwitchMaterial chb = View.FindViewById<SwitchMaterial>(Resource.Id.chbCap);
    var value = Preferences.Get("DefCapacità", "24");

    if (value == e.Id.ToString()) chb.Checked = true;
    else  chb.Checked = false;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).